# Threads in Waiting state - Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, threadpool

We have deployed our Remedy mid-tier on Tomcat 6.0.20, however Tomcat goes down very frequently, almost every day, with the following error :

Maximum number of threads (400) created for address null and port 8080

We have tried increasing the the number of threads, but it just does not suffice. The time difference between 2 subsequent crashes just increases, but it is the same problem.

We have obtained the thread dump, and it shows that most of the threads are in 'Waiting' state. Please refer below obtained from thread logs as follows:

```
 *"http-8080-670" - Thread t@8479
 java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for <775f1471> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.apitransport.connection.a.get(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.apitransport.connection.c.getProxy(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.PoolingProxyManager.getProxy(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.apitransport.connection.c.getProxy(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.arsys.api.ARServerUser.getListEntryObjects(Unknown Source)
            at com.remedy.arsys.goat.savesearches.ARUserSearches.loadFromServer(Unknown Source)
              - locked <32e7e815> (a com.remedy.arsys.goat.savesearches.ARUserSearches)
             at com.remedy.arsys.goat.aspects.IARUserSearchesServiceCacheAspect.ajc$around$com_remedy_arsys_goat_aspects_IARUserSearchesServiceCacheAspect$1$181ba497(IARUserSearchesServiceCacheAspect.aj:44)
            - locked <794bbdbc> (a java.lang.String)
            at com.remedy.arsys.goat.savesearches.ARUserSearches.getUserSearches(Unknown Source)
            at com.remedy.arsys.goat.UserDataEmitter.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.remedy.arsys.goat.service.DHTMLRequestService.requestDispatch(Unknown Source)
            at com.remedy.arsys.stubs.FormServlet.doRequest(Unknown Source)
            at com.remedy.arsys.stubs.GoatServlet.postInternal(Unknown Source)
            at com.remedy.arsys.stubs.GoatHttpServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Locked ownable synchronizers:
            - locked <5b95bfda> (a       java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)*
```

There are many reasons for the threads being in 'Waiting', can anyone help to narrow down.

Comment: Are all the other threads stuck at the same place? This thread dump is showing only one thread.

Answer (score 0):

The threads appear to be waiting but in fact they are blocked inside a working queue. Looks like they use a ThreadPoolExecutor to schedule tasks but there is not enough threads in the working queue to process all the tasks, or each task is taking too long.

Have a look at : [Deadlock in ThreadPoolExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393139/772000).

Also, inspect the `PoolingProxyManager`, what is he `getProxy` supposed to do, it looks like it is trying to get connection or some other resource.

Answer (score 0):

The thread enters into `park` state when it has not given chance for execution (ie; number of threads which are in the pool) in the pool. The pool refers to the thread which are currently in `RUN` state. When the pool gets filled the thread enters the queue which would be in `WAIT` state and gets chance to enter into `RUN` state when it gets chance to enter into the pool for execution.

When the threshold for `pool` and `queue` exceeds the thread enters into `park WAIT` state and they would wait until anyone of the following things happens,

i) When it exceeds the configured park time out

or

ii) It gets `permit` to enter into the `pool` or `queue` ie; The thread would get chance to enter into `RUN` or  `WAIT` state when `Thread.interrupt()` is invoked.